# Remove anything from string after any "a-zA-Z" char

Tags: c#, string

I have this types of `string`:

```
"10a10", "10b5641", "5a1121", "438z2a5f"
```

and I need to remove anything after the *FIRST* `a-zA-Z` char in the string (the symbol itself should be removed as well). What could be a solution?

Examples of results I expect:

```
"10a10"    returns "10" 
"10b5641"  returns "10" 
"5a1121"   returns "5" 
"438z2a5f" returns "438"
```

Comment: You say "after", but mean "including"? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Regular Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) along with [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2), something like:

```
string str = "10a10";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-zA-Z].*", "");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

will output:

```
10
```

Basically it will takes everything that starts with `a-zA-Z` and everything after it (`.*` matches any characters zero or unlimited times) and remove it from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could do so using Linq as follows.

```
var result = new string(strInput.TakeWhile(x => !char.IsLetter(x)).ToArray());
```

Comment: a) You don't need that `.ToCharArray()`. b) That `.IsLetter` will stop at more than just "a-zA-Z", but I don't think the distinction will matter to the OP

Answer (score 1):

An easy to understand approach would be to use the String.IndexOfAny Method to find the Index of the first a-zA-Z char, and then use the String.Substring Method to cut the string accordingly.

To do so you would create an array containing all a-zA-Z characters and use this as an argument to String.IndexOfAny. After that you use 0 and the result of String.IndexOfAny as arguments for String.Substring.

I am pretty sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but this seems the most basic approach to me, so its worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Either *Linq*:

```
var result = string.Concat(strInput
  .TakeWhile(c => !((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')));
```

Or *regular expression*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var result = Regex.Match(strInput, "^[^A-Za-z]*").Value;
```

In both cases starting from `strInput` beginning take characters until `a..z` or `A-Z` occurred

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new[] {
    "10a10", "10b5641", "5a1121", "438z2a5f"
  };

  string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-10} returns \"{Regex.Match(test, "^[^A-Za-z]*").Value}\""));

  Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
10a10      returns "10"
10b5641    returns "10"
5a1121     returns "5"
438z2a5f   returns "438"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var sList = new List<string> { "10a10", "10b5641", "5a1121", "438z2a5f" };
            foreach (string s in sList.ToArray())
            {
                string number = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
```